# Tell composer which PHP version to use

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

I have two projects running php7.0 and 5.6. Now the default version of php cli is 7.0. I need to run composer-update on project 5.6 but the composer is reading php7.0 so it will throw an error since there are features that only compatible in 5.6. Is there a way to tell composer which version to use during composer-install and composer-update without changing the default php-cli?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you just have to specify which PHP version to use by directly calling the intended PHP bin file.

So, instead of

```
php composer.phar update
```

You have to use something like

```
/path/to/php5.6/bin/php composer.phar update
```

In my case, on a CentOS server with Plesk (default PHP version was 5.4, but I also had 5.6 and 7.0 installed), I had to use :

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php composer.phar update
```

Comment: Hi @roberto06, I tried your command but it gives me an error "Could not open input file: composer.phar". Btw, I'm using linux mint.

Comment: @Makubex you can get your php path via `phpinfo();`

Comment: Or via `which php` or `whereis php` directly on your server.

Comment: Hi php tells me this path " /usr/bin/php5.6". So I use "/usr/bin/php5.6 composer.phar update" but still got the same error

Comment: you also need to provide the absolute path for composer.phar

Comment: @roberto06 i think this will prompt the cli php path

Comment: Or work directly in the directory where `composer.phar` is.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the help. Its working now, I just need to include the absolute path of composer also. Thanks!